# Tab complete the folder names using python Cmd library

Tags: python, sockets, cmd, tab-completion

Hello wonderful people,

I am writing a client server program which basically gives me a [bind shell](https://www.go4expert.com/articles/difference-bind-shell-reverse-shell-t25408/). I using Cmd library for auto completion of filenames and folders inside the bind shell. I am writing **do_cd** and **complete_cd** functions for the auto completion.

So far I am just able to tab complete the sub folders of the current folder.

my **complete_cd** function looks like this right now:

```
def complete_cd(self, text, line, begidx, endidx):
    if not text:
        completions = self.subfolders[:] #subfolders contains list of sub folders of current folder
    else:
        completions = [f for f in self.subfolders if f.startswith(text)]
```

I am stuck at a point where I want to tab complete something like following:
cd /us{tab}/sh{tab} which should do **cd /usr/share**.
What I tried to do was I fetched all the folder paths using os.walk('/') from the client and appended it to a list. Now, on the basis of number of slashes, I created a dictionary. for example: dict.get(1) will contain **'/dev\n/home\n/media\n....'** i.e. folders with only one slash, dict.get(2) will contain **'/etc/apache2\n/etc/apt\n....'** i.e. folders with two slashes and so on.

But I don't know how to put this logic in complete_cd function.

What I tried to write is this:

```
if text.startswith('/'):
    slash_counter = text.count('/')
    dir_list = list(filter(None, self.dict[slash_counter].split('\n')))
    completions = [f for f in dir_list if f.startswith(text)]
```

If anyone can suggest any other approach then that is also fine.

Any help is appreciated!